# indexError: list index out of range (Сложение значений из файла)

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Дан фаил, в нем 4 столбца, (индекс, возраст, рост(дюймы), вес(фунты)) длинна файла 20000+
задача следующая, нужно сложить вес и рост, и получить среднее значение(я пытался еще перевести дюймы и фунты в *см и кг*)
я сложил столб и поделил на количество, но получаю вот такую вот ошибку
**mean += float(line[1])  # [1] - второй столбец в файле
IndexError: list index out of range**

```
def data_scv():
    with open('data.csv') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        next(csv_reader)
        mean = 0
        n = 0
        for line in csv_reader:
            mean += float(line[1])  # [2] - второй столбец в файле
            n += 1
            ave_height = str((mean / n) * 2.54)
        for line in csv_reader:
            mean += float(line[2])  # [3] - третий столбец в файле
            n += 1
            ave_weight = str((mean / n) / 2.205)

        return f'Average Height(Centimeters) is - {ave_height} <br> Average Height(Kilograms) is - {ave_weight}'
```

Comment: в какой строчке? Что там еще написано?

Comment: @Эникейщик mean += len(line[1])  # [1] - второй столбец в файле

Comment: значит нужно перед этой строкой вставить print(line) и посмотреть, действительно ли в line то, что ожидается

Comment: @Эникейщик если поставить print(line) вывод все данные из файла

Comment: ну вот, это не то, что хотелось бы иметь в переменной line, так ведь.  Ищи причину и исправляй

Comment: Какой у вас разделитель колонок в файле? Если не запятая, то у вас файл будет прочитан как будто там одна колонка. Нужно в csv.reader через параметр delimiter указать правильный разделитель, например `csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')`, если разделитель - точка с запятой.

Comment: @insolor запятая, уже поправил

Comment: @insolor я сейчас пытаюсь, сделать в одном цикле, и без *n* так как длину массива можно через функцию *len* узнать